# How to convert RIGHT LEFT functions to codeigniter active record

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(id, 1) id_root
FROM  user 
WHERE LENGTH(id) = 3
and LEFT(id, 1) = '0'
```

And how to convert that's query to active record in `codeigniter`.

My problem is with syntax `RIGHT( id, 1 )` and also at `LEFT(id,1)='0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce your query like this

```
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->select('RIGHT(id, 1) id_root',false);
$this->db->where('LENGTH(id)',3,true);
$this->db->where('LEFT(id, 1) =','0',true);
$results=$this->db->get()->result();
```

Remember if you want to use mysql function at your select query which may break mysql syntax by codeigniter use false as 2nd parameter so that codeigniter does not protect/covert your fields.

Same for where, if you want to use mysql function or other function which may break mysql syntax by CI use 3rd parameter as true so that codeigniter does not convert your fields.

See details at [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Simplest way to get any query result using `$this->db->query('YOUR_QUERY')` But I prefer using CI Active record's functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $result_arr = $this->db
        ->select("RIGHT(id, 1) id_root", FALSE)
        ->from("user")
        ->where(
                array("LENGTH(id)"=> 3, "LEFT(id, 1) =" => 0)
        )->get()
        ->result_array();
```

Or you can simply use `$this->db->query("You SQL");`

```
$query = "SELECT RIGHT(id, 1) id_root
          FROM  user 
          WHERE LENGTH(id) = ?
          and LEFT(id, 1) = ? ";
$result_arr = $this->db->query($query, array(3, 0))->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT RIGHT(id, 1) id_root
          FROM  user 
          WHERE LENGTH(id) = 3
          and LEFT(id, 1) = '0'";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```